# python3 -m http.server needing two terminals?

Tags: python, linux, httpserver

I'm going through the "Linux Fundamentals" section on TryHackMe, and I was asked to start a web server using Python's "HTTPServer" module and download a file from said server. My first line of code was `python3 -m http.server` to initiate the server, then in the Linux terminal all I had was a blank line, no directory or prompt or anything. I input `wget http://ip.address:port/filename` with the correct IP address, port, and filename but nothing ran. It took me opening another terminal window in order to download the file, is this correct or have I missed something? This is my first introduction to Linux so I apologise if I've missed something simple.

Comment: `python3 -m http.server` is blocking your terminal, its running in the foreground! so either send it to the background `python3 -m http.server&` which will still print to your terminal when things happen (you can redirect the output to a file if you want) or do like you did and use a second terminal

Comment: Anyway, this method is used to upload some file on a remote target, so you would forcibly use 2 terminals: your PC and the remote shell on the target.
It wouldn't make a lot of sense to download a file on your own machine with a http server